# Trying to use JSON but getting '500 Internal Server Error'

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm back with another question.

I'm trying to create a JSON file that gets data from my MySQL database. The thing is, I'm getting the '500 Internal Server Error' message.

The Code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!isset($_GET['query'])) {
    echo json_encode([]);
    exit();
}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydbname', 'mydbuser', 'mydbpaswd');

$users = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE :query");

$users->execute(['query' => "{$_GET['query']}%"]);

echo json_encode($users->fetchAll());
?>
```

I typed in http://mylink.com/users.php?query=ch this should have given me a page with possible usernames starting with 'ch'.

P.S. I used basic names for some things to not show my actual names.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Check your error log

Comment: What version of PHP are you running ? That array syntax could be the problem.

Comment: @TomToms I'm running version 5.3.3

Comment: @rjdown No errors found.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: @Gordon I have error reporting enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$array = ['myindex' => 'somevalue']` syntax for arrays  has been [implemented in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Try with `array()` instead.

Comment: I'll try upgrading my PHP from 5.3.3 to a newer version and will report back once it's done. Thanks for your comment.